# Historical bandwidth data in a console? (save/load statistics)

Tags: shell, networking, monitoring, console, bandwidth

So, I found that nload and iftop displays the amount of data that passed and how fast. Now, is there anything like those that can save/load statistics?

I want to measure the amount of data I download over a month/year. Suggestions will really help.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking for `atop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File "/proc/net/dev" has information about trannsmited and recieved packages for every interface your computer has. I guess you could make a script to time the packages and get the bandwith since you have data in its raw form.